# "Can't read superblock" when trying to boot . Failed to mount /dev/mapper/xxxxxxx on real root

Tags: lvm, boot, arch-linux, btrfs

I finished setting up my new Arch system about a month ago. Since I had two nvme drives to use for the system I did some research on how I could use both of them to utilize the full capacity of both drives. nvme0n1 is a 2 TB drive (KIOXIA EXCERIA PLUS G2) and nvme3n1 is a 1 TB drive (CRUCIAL P5). Followed the Arch WiKi to install Arch on an BTRFS partition created on the logical volume consisting of the two physical volumes.
A couple of days ago my system drive became read only with no apparent reason. I rebooted and everything was back to normal - and stupid me I didn't pay any attention to the incident. This morning it happened again so I rebooted and then my system couldn't boot any more.
The message was

```
mount: /new_root: can't read superblock on /dev/mapper/vg.fermat-lv.fermat
ERROR: Failed to mount '/dev/mapper/vg.fermat -lv.fermat' on real root
You are now being dropped into an emergency shell.
```

I am now booted into a live cd, trying to figure out the solution to my problem but I am stuck. Here's my situation

```
[root@ArcoLinuxB-plasma liveuser]# pvdisplay
--- Physical volume ---
PV Name               /dev/nvme0n1p2
VG Name               vg.fermat
PV Size               <1.82 TiB / not usable 4.00 MiB
Allocatable           yes (but full)
PE Size               4.00 MiB
Total PE              476803
Free PE               0
Allocated PE          476803
PV UUID               1yXIyW-r3kZ-TRRW-VyVs-dwtW-GtWZ-HA2BkO
  
--- Physical volume ---
PV Name               /dev/nvme3n1p1
VG Name               vg.fermat
PV Size               931.51 GiB / not usable 4.00 MiB
Allocatable           yes (but full)
PE Size               4.00 MiB
Total PE              238466
Free PE               0
Allocated PE          238466
PV UUID               B4BQsn-pffm-fMfw-QjPb-22da-v13l-vbcoiz


[root@ArcoLinuxB-plasma liveuser]# vgdisplay
--- Volume group ---
VG Name               vg.fermat
System ID             
Format                lvm2
Metadata Areas        2
Metadata Sequence No  2
VG Access             read/write
VG Status             resizable
MAX LV                0
Cur LV                1
Open LV               0
Max PV                0
Cur PV                2
Act PV                2
VG Size               <2.73 TiB
PE Size               4.00 MiB
Total PE              715269
Alloc PE / Size       715269 / <2.73 TiB
Free  PE / Size       0 / 0   
VG UUID               ayLDzU-tD0J-AQyN-G3lV-BdgH-wn9D-TbRZsp

[root@ArcoLinuxB-plasma liveuser]# lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg.fermat/lv.fermat
  LV Name                lv.fermat
  VG Name                vg.fermat
  LV UUID                NxCCrP-cA6K-4eZh-2O2p-gaBs-rSex-jh2MJR
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time archiso, 2023-11-27 15:49:45 +0000
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                <2.73 TiB
  Current LE             715269
  Segments               2
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           254:1

[root@ArcoLinuxB-plasma liveuser]# mount /dev/vg.fermat/lv.fermat /mnt/test
mount: /mnt/test: can't read superblock on /dev/mapper/vg.fermat-lv.fermat.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.

[root@ArcoLinuxB-plasma liveuser]# dumpe2fs -h /dev/vg.fermat/lv.fermat
dumpe2fs 1.47.0 (5-Feb-2023)
dumpe2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/vg.fermat/lv.fermat
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
/dev/vg.fermat/lv.fermat contains a btrfs file system labelled 'Root'

[root@ArcoLinuxB-plasma liveuser]# dumpe2fs -h /dev/nvme0n1
dumpe2fs 1.47.0 (5-Feb-2023)
dumpe2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/nvme0n1
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
/dev/nvme0n1 contains `DOS/MBR boot sector; partition 1 : ID=0xee, start-CHS (0x0,0,2), end-CHS (0x3ff,255,63), startsector 1, 3907029167 sectors, extended partition table (last)' data

[root@ArcoLinuxB-plasma liveuser]# dumpe2fs -h /dev/nvme3n1
dumpe2fs 1.47.0 (5-Feb-2023)
dumpe2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/nvme3n1
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
/dev/nvme3n1 contains `DOS/MBR boot sector; partition 1 : ID=0xee, start-CHS (0x0,0,2), end-CHS (0x3ff,255,63), startsector 1, 1953525167 sectors, extended partition table (last)' data
```

I don't know if it helps but here's my fdisk info as well

```
[root@ArcoLinuxB-plasma liveuser]# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: T-FORCE 1TB     
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: F844A08E-4F0E-46B5-B392-B36AAF2495D3

Device     Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1   2048 1953523711 1953521664 931.5G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sdb: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: T-FORCE 1TB     
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 9D2D5B13-1C00-554A-9F37-400A05AC3B5F

Device     Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048 1953521663 1953519616 931.5G Microsoft basic data


Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: KIOXIA-EXCERIA PLUS G2 SSD              
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: C61199F3-F473-42D5-80B5-60BD7C0DFE06

Device           Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1    2048    1050623    1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 1050624 3907028991 3905978368  1.8T Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/nvme2n1: 476.94 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 960 PRO 512GB               
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 1E1A4C9E-E48E-4848-9EC6-DCB3FA1A5817

Device             Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme2n1p1      2048     206847    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/nvme2n1p2    206848     239615     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme2n1p3    239616  998932479 998692864 476.2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme2n1p4 998932480 1000212479   1280000   625M Windows recovery environment


Disk /dev/nvme1n1: 476.94 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 960 PRO 512GB               
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 8FCA4CDE-8E68-47B8-A973-991CCEE89354

Device          Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme1n1p1     40     409639    409600   200M EFI System
/dev/nvme1n1p2 409640 1000215175 999805536 476.7G Apple APFS


Disk /dev/nvme3n1: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: CT1000P5PSSD8                           
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: B76AA81C-93F9-4489-8E50-7AF9B725D84F

Device         Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme3n1p1  2048 1953523711 1953521664 931.5G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sdc: 58.59 GiB, 62914560000 bytes, 122880000 sectors
Disk model: MyUSB Drive     
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xf70f22b6

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1  *         2048 122814463 122812416 58.6G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdc2       122814464 122879999     65536   32M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)


Disk /dev/mapper/ventoy: 2.45 GiB, 2634657792 bytes, 5145816 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xfcb65ee5

Device                   Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mapper/ventoy-part1 *         64 5114431 5114368  2.4G  0 Empty
/dev/mapper/ventoy-part2      5114432 5145151   30720   15M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)


Disk /dev/loop0: 2.31 GiB, 2481229824 bytes, 4846152 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/vg.fermat-lv.fermat: 2.73 TiB, 3000055627776 bytes, 5859483648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

From what I read in other posts I need to locate a backup superblock, replace the bad one and then maybe repair the logical volume (?). Any ideas on how to proceed? And why this happened in the first place?

Thanks for your attention...

***EDIT 1***

I managed to get some info about backup superblocks by running

```
[root@ArcoLinuxB-plasma liveuser]# mke2fs -n /dev/vg.fermat/lv.fermat
mke2fs 1.47.0 (5-Feb-2023)
/dev/vg.fermat/lv.fermat contains a btrfs file system labelled 'Root'
Proceed anyway? (y,N) y
Creating filesystem with 732435456 4k blocks and 183115776 inodes
Filesystem UUID: 3964e616-a731-49c1-80e5-e27777a87a39
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
        32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
        4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872, 71663616, 78675968, 
        102400000, 214990848, 512000000, 550731776, 644972544
```

***EDIT 2***
Running `smartctl` on both disks gives me some weird results

```
[root@ArcoLinuxB-plasma liveuser]# smartctl -a /dev/nvme0n1
smartctl 7.4 2023-08-01 r5530 [x86_64-linux-6.5.8-arch1-1] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-23, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       KIOXIA-EXCERIA PLUS G2 SSD
Serial Number:                      61AA1019KLF2
Firmware Version:                   ECFA11.1
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0x1e0f
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x8ce38e
Total NVM Capacity:                 2,000,398,934,016 [2.00 TB]
Unallocated NVM Capacity:           0
Controller ID:                      1
NVMe Version:                       1.3
Number of Namespaces:               1
Namespace 1 Size/Capacity:          2,000,398,934,016 [2.00 TB]
Namespace 1 Formatted LBA Size:     512
Namespace 1 IEEE EUI-64:            8ce38e 030068c2cf
Local Time is:                      Mon Dec 18 09:10:33 2023 UTC
Firmware Updates (0x12):            1 Slot, no Reset required
Optional Admin Commands (0x0017):   Security Format Frmw_DL Self_Test
Optional NVM Commands (0x005f):     Comp Wr_Unc DS_Mngmt Wr_Zero Sav/Sel_Feat Timestmp
Log Page Attributes (0x0a):         Cmd_Eff_Lg Telmtry_Lg
Maximum Data Transfer Size:         512 Pages
Warning  Comp. Temp. Threshold:     72 Celsius
Critical Comp. Temp. Threshold:     90 Celsius

Supported Power States
St Op     Max   Active     Idle   RL RT WL WT  Ent_Lat  Ex_Lat
 0 +    11.09W       -        -    0  0  0  0        1       1
 1 +     8.05W       -        -    1  1  1  1        1       1
 2 +     6.54W       -        -    2  2  2  2        1       1
 3 -   0.0500W       -        -    3  3  3  3     7000    5000
 4 -   0.0050W       -        -    4  4  4  4    13000   36000

Supported LBA Sizes (NSID 0x1)
Id Fmt  Data  Metadt  Rel_Perf
 0 +     512       0         2
 1 -    4096       0         1

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x00
Temperature:                        33 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          5%
Percentage Used:                    1%
Data Units Read:                    925,560 [473 GB]
Data Units Written:                 6,645,795 [3.40 TB]
Host Read Commands:                 7,141,610
Host Write Commands:                72,308,821
Controller Busy Time:               74
Power Cycles:                       35
Power On Hours:                     389
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   13
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    0
Error Information Log Entries:      394
Warning  Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Critical Comp. Temperature Time:    0

Error Information (NVMe Log 0x01, 16 of 63 entries)
Num   ErrCount  SQId   CmdId  Status  PELoc          LBA  NSID    VS  Message
  0        394     0  0x8015  0x4004  0x004            0     1     -  Invalid Field in Command
  1        393     0  0x800b  0x4004  0x004            0     1     -  Invalid Field in Command
  2        392     0  0x200d  0x4004  0x004            0     1     -  Invalid Field in Command
  3        391     0  0x7014  0x4004  0x004            0     1     -  Invalid Field in Command
  4        390     0  0x100c  0x4004  0x004            0     1     -  Invalid Field in Command
  5        389     0  0x0000  0x4004  0x028            0     0     -  Invalid Field in Command

Read Self-test Log failed: Invalid Field in Command (0x2002)
```

And

```
[root@ArcoLinuxB-plasma liveuser]# smartctl -a /dev/nvme3n1
smartctl 7.4 2023-08-01 r5530 [x86_64-linux-6.5.8-arch1-1] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-23, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       CT1000P5PSSD8
Serial Number:                      22343ACCCC43
Firmware Version:                   P7CR403
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0xc0a9
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x00a075
Total NVM Capacity:                 1,000,204,886,016 [1.00 TB]
Unallocated NVM Capacity:           0
Controller ID:                      0
NVMe Version:                       1.4
Number of Namespaces:               1
Namespace 1 Size/Capacity:          1,000,204,886,016 [1.00 TB]
Namespace 1 Formatted LBA Size:     512
Namespace 1 IEEE EUI-64:            00a075 013acccc43
Local Time is:                      Mon Dec 18 09:11:17 2023 UTC
Firmware Updates (0x14):            2 Slots, no Reset required
Optional Admin Commands (0x0017):   Security Format Frmw_DL Self_Test
Optional NVM Commands (0x0057):     Comp Wr_Unc DS_Mngmt Sav/Sel_Feat Timestmp
Log Page Attributes (0x1b):         S/H_per_NS Cmd_Eff_Lg Telmtry_Lg Pers_Ev_Lg
Maximum Data Transfer Size:         512 Pages
Warning  Comp. Temp. Threshold:     80 Celsius
Critical Comp. Temp. Threshold:     82 Celsius
Namespace 1 Features (0x08):        No_ID_Reuse

Supported Power States
St Op     Max   Active     Idle   RL RT WL WT  Ent_Lat  Ex_Lat
 0 +     8.25W       -        -    0  0  0  0        0       0
 1 +     4.00W       -        -    1  1  1  1        0       0
 2 +     2.00W       -        -    2  2  2  2        0       0
 3 -   0.1000W       -        -    3  3  3  3     5000    6000
 4 -   0.0050W       -        -    4  4  4  4    12000   35000

Supported LBA Sizes (NSID 0x1)
Id Fmt  Data  Metadt  Rel_Perf
 0 +     512       0         0

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x00
Temperature:                        35 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          5%
Percentage Used:                    1%
Data Units Read:                    6,706,996 [3.43 TB]
Data Units Written:                 10,961,060 [5.61 TB]
Host Read Commands:                 53,749,530
Host Write Commands:                177,816,661
Controller Busy Time:               160
Power Cycles:                       95
Power On Hours:                     810
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   51
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    0
Error Information Log Entries:      541
Warning  Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Critical Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Temperature Sensor 1:               35 Celsius

Error Information (NVMe Log 0x01, 16 of 256 entries)
Num   ErrCount  SQId   CmdId  Status  PELoc          LBA  NSID    VS  Message
  0        541     0  0x000c  0x8004  0x000            0     0     -  Invalid Field in Command

Read Self-test Log failed: Invalid Field in Command (0x002)
```

So it passes the health test but there are some unidentifiable errors in the log.

***EDIT 3***

At this stage I have no idea what the heck is happening. Is it a hardware problem with one of the disks, is it a problem with `lvm` or is it a problem with the `btrfs` partition on the logical volume ?

I think I need to answer this question first before I proceed with any repair attempts utilizing the available backup superblocks ...

Comment: Are the disks still ok? Can you check with smartctl. For example `smartctl -a /dev/nvme0n1`

Comment: Thanks for replying. Please see my edits above.

Comment: For your info, you don't need to use LVM when using BTRFS, or in other words, you don't want to use LVM when using BTRFS, cause BTRFS has a inbuilt LVM which is more robust and performant.